# 301="Moved Permanently" curl php

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estou a desenvolver um sistema, porem está dando esse erro no curl. Alguém sabe informar o que pode ser?

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente você precisa aceitar redirecionamentos.

Acrescente o parâmetro `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` ao Curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Isso irá habilitar para seguir o header "Location:", de sua requisição, assim o Curl irá seguir o redirecionamento previsto pelo erro 301.

Você pode definir a quantidade de redirecionamentos, usando `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` junto ao Curl, por exemplo:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
```

O `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` tem a função de limitar o número de redirecionamentos, neste caso 5, mas pode ser alterado.

*Você também pode usar o `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER` para atualizar o "Referer:" para o último "Location:" obtido, pode ser necessário em alguns casos.*