# Como acompanhar redirecionamento Curl PHP?

Tags: php

Uso o `curl` para capturar dados de uma página, mas está retornando o código `301` (movido). Usei `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, mas continua na mesma. Alguém sabe como acompanhar o redirecionamento?

Comment: Poste o código de como você tentou.

Comment: e o link do curl

Comment: Pode também encontrar a resposta em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71275/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126095/3635

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente uma configuração como essa é o suficiente

```
// Inicia o cURL
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); // tempo em segundos
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); // em segundos
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // true: permite redirecionamento
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1); // quantidade limite de redirecionamentos permitidos

//daqui em diante você define e outros parâmetros, etc.
```

Veja também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123883/4793

Answer (score -2):

Geralmente não sei se vc já esta fazendo isso use a opção -L para ele acompanhar o redirecionamento.
Caso contrário acesse o endereço pelo navegador e apos o redirecionamento substitua a URL pela nova.

```
curl -L <URL>
```

Comment: Provavelmente negativaram porque a pergunta é relacionada ao PHP, sua resposta é para o cURL na linha de comando.